# How can I create a native component of Android in ReactNative using Here Maps SDK

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, here-api

I'm here looking for knowledgment about how to use Here Maps SDK in React Native.
(https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-explore/4.14.1.0/dev_guide/topics/quick-start.html#say-hello-map)

I know React Native, that part is not a problem. But I can't say I know how Android works...

My question is about how can I create a full size map in my React Native app, using Fragments.
Following the React Native documentation in order to creat an Android Native UI Component :

I need a custom view:

```js
// replace with your package
package com.mypackage;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

public class CustomView extends FrameLayout {
  public CustomView(@NonNull Context context) {
    super(context);
    // set padding and background color
    this.setPadding(16,16,16,16);
    this.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#5FD3F3"));

    // add default text view
    TextView text = new TextView(context);
    text.setText("Welcome to Android Fragments with React Native.");
    this.addView(text);
  }
}
```

A Fragment to add views, because I think you can get different fragments with different funcitonalities and views:

```js
// replace with your package
package com.mypackage;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

// replace with your view's import
import com.mypackage.CustomView;

public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    CustomView customView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, parent, savedInstanceState);
        customView = new CustomView(this.getContext());
        return customView; // this CustomView could be any view that you want to render
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        // do any logic that should happen in an `onCreate` method, e.g:
        // customView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // do any logic that should happen in an `onPause` method
        // e.g.: customView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
       // do any logic that should happen in an `onResume` method
       // e.g.: customView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // do any logic that should happen in an `onDestroy` method
        // e.g.: customView.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

A ViewManager (Honestly I don't know what the purpose of this is):

```js
// replace with your package
package com.mypackage;

import android.view.Choreographer;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableArray;
import com.facebook.react.common.MapBuilder;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.annotations.ReactProp;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.annotations.ReactPropGroup;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewGroupManager;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ThemedReactContext;

import java.util.Map;

public class MyViewManager extends ViewGroupManager<FrameLayout> {

  public static final String REACT_CLASS = "MyViewManager";
  public final int COMMAND_CREATE = 1;
  private int propWidth;
  private int propHeight;

  ReactApplicationContext reactContext;

  public MyViewManager(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    this.reactContext = reactContext;
  }

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return REACT_CLASS;
  }

  /**
   * Return a FrameLayout which will later hold the Fragment
   */
  @Override
  public FrameLayout createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext reactContext) {
    return new FrameLayout(reactContext);
  }

  /**
   * Map the "create" command to an integer
   */
  @Nullable
  @Override
  public Map<String, Integer> getCommandsMap() {
    return MapBuilder.of("create", COMMAND_CREATE);
  }

  /**
   * Handle "create" command (called from JS) and call createFragment method
   */
  @Override
  public void receiveCommand(
    @NonNull FrameLayout root,
    String commandId,
    @Nullable ReadableArray args
  ) {
    super.receiveCommand(root, commandId, args);
    int reactNativeViewId = args.getInt(0);
    int commandIdInt = Integer.parseInt(commandId);

    switch (commandIdInt) {
      case COMMAND_CREATE:
        createFragment(root, reactNativeViewId);
        break;
      default: {}
    }
  }

  @ReactPropGroup(names = {"width", "height"}, customType = "Style")
  public void setStyle(FrameLayout view, int index, Integer value) {
    if (index == 0) {
      propWidth = value;
    }

    if (index == 1) {
      propHeight = value;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Replace your React Native view with a custom fragment
   */
  public void createFragment(FrameLayout root, int reactNativeViewId) {
    ViewGroup parentView = (ViewGroup) root.findViewById(reactNativeViewId);
    setupLayout(parentView);

    final MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
    FragmentActivity activity = (FragmentActivity) reactContext.getCurrentActivity();
    activity.getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(reactNativeViewId, myFragment, String.valueOf(reactNativeViewId))
            .commit();
  }

  public void setupLayout(View view) {
    Choreographer.getInstance().postFrameCallback(new Choreographer.FrameCallback() {
      @Override
      public void doFrame(long frameTimeNanos) {
        manuallyLayoutChildren(view);
        view.getViewTreeObserver().dispatchOnGlobalLayout();
        Choreographer.getInstance().postFrameCallback(this);
      }
    });
  }

  /**
   * Layout all children properly
   */
  public void manuallyLayoutChildren(View view) {
      // propWidth and propHeight coming from react-native props
      int width = propWidth;
      int height = propHeight;

      view.measure(
              View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
              View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));

      view.layout(0, 0, width, height);
  }
}
```

And next steps are not difficult because they are only steps about how you can connect React Native and Android.

My main problem is Can I use a MapView instance as a View inside of a FrameLayout? And How Can I set a full width/height measure?

Thanks,
Pelayo

Comment: Hi. We have a sample project you can use as a reference, but it cannot be shared here. If you can contact Here Support via the Portal so you can make a proper case, we can hand it to you. Just beware that React Native is not officially supported, so you are mostly on your own after receiving the sample.